# SAS: perform a procedure on a list of variables via macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have some dataset `dataset` with a large number of variables, and I want to perform some function on a subset of the variables using `proc sql`, such as the code below:

```
proc sql;
   select col1, col2, col3
   from dataset
   where col1 = . OR
         col2 = . OR
         col3 = .;
quit;
```

I want this be executed in a macro, as this code will be repeated many times over using different (and a different number of) columns. So, I am looking for a solution that would implement the `proc`  by calling a macro with a list of variable names:

```
%some_macro(list_of_columns)
```

Apologies if I haven't explained too well, I usually work in (and much prefer) R!

Answer (score 3):

To pass a list of values to a macro it is best to use a single parameter.  You can use a delimiter to separate the values you pass in.  It is better to NOT use comma as the delimiter because comma is already used in the macro calling syntax.

Do you really need to generate SQL code?  That is a pain because SQL syntax uses a lot of commas also.  Your example would be MUCH easier to do with normal SAS syntax instead.

```
%macro some_macro(list_of_columns);
proc print data=dataset;
  var &list_of_columns;
  where cmiss(of &list_of_columns);
run;
%mend some_macro ;

%some_macro(col1 colB anothercolumn)
```

If you do need to use the list with SQL code you could add back the commas.

You could do it by looping.

```
%do index=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list_of_columns,%str( ));
  %let column=%scan(&list_of_columns,&index,%str( ));
  ... code that used &COLUMN ...
%end;
```

Or perhaps by use TRANWRD() or TRANSLATE() to convert the delimiter into comma.

```
%let sql_list=%sysfunc(translate(&list_of_columns,%str(,),%str( )));

....  select &sql_list from dataset ....
```